# How to use Mockito to test APIs along Robospice and Retrofit?

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, robospice, retrofit

I've been following this [blog entry](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2013/12/16/reliable-android-http-testing-with-retrofit-and-mockito.html) which shows how to mock requests with Mockito and Retrofit. The problem is I'm using both along Robospice, which it doesn't require to provide a `Callback` as parameter on the service interface (as it would be a [synchronous call](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)):

```
@GET("/foo/bar")
User foo(@Query("bar") String baz);
```

So I cannot intercept the callback on my tests on this way:

```
Mockito.verify(mockApi).repositories(Mockito.anyString(), cb.capture());
User user = new User();
cb.getValue().success(user, null);
```

Is any way to achieve this?. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mock the service interface and then script it to return the value you desire.

```
doReturn(new User()).when(service).foo(anyString());
```

You can later verify that this method was called.

```
verify(service).foo(anyString())
```

Comment: What do you mean by Mock the service?